# bin directory ends up empty when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying my hand at Ruby on Rails, and I'm having a problem deploying my first app to Heroku.  It was working perfectly previously, but Heroku was complaining about SQLite3.  I changed to Postgres using these instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3.

Now I can deploy the app successfully, except that it crashes immediately when starting it, because `bin/rails` does not exist.  I used `git:clone` to pull a copy of the code from Heroku, and the `bin` directory is empty.  The original `bin` directory has all the necessary files to run the app locally.

What would cause the `bin` directory to upload empty, while all the other files upload without a hitch?

Comment: Check if the `bin` directory is excluded in the `.gitignore` file on your local repo.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy, thanks, but there is no `.gitignore`.  I searched the system for `.gitignore`, and `bin` is not mentioned in either of the two files I did find.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue simple excluding `bin` directory from linked_dirs variable.

It was

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('bin', 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
```

and became

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
```

But this solution will not suit you if you have any custom executables need to be persisted between deploys.